# Sentiment analysis feature extraction

Tags: word2vec, feature-extraction, nlp-question-answering

I am new to NLP and feature extraction, i wish to create a machine learning model that can determine the sentiment of stock related social media posts. For feature extraction of my dataset I have opted to use Word2Vec. My question is:

Is it important to train my word2vec model on a corpus of stock related social media posts - the datasets that are available for this are not very large. Should I just use a much larger pretrained word vector ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to to tell what will work better for your goals, within your constraints of data/resources/time, is to try alternate approaches & compare the results on a repeatable quantititave evaluation.

Having training texts that are properly representative of your domain-of-interest can be quite important. You may need your representation of the word 'interest', for example, to represent that of stock/financial world, rather than the more general sense of the word.

But quantity of data is also quite important. With smaller datasets, *none* of your words may get great vectors, and words important to evaluating new posts may be missing or of very-poor quality. In some cases taking some pretrained set-of-vectors, with its larger vocabulary & sharper (but slightly-mismatched to domain) word-senses may be a net help.

Because these pull in different directions, there's no general answer. It will depend on *your* data, goals, limits, & skills. Only trying a range of alternative approaches, and comparing them, will tell you what should be done for your situation.

As this iterative, comparative experimental pattern repeats endlessly as your projects & knowledge grow – it's what the experts do! – it's also important to learn, & practice. There's no authority you can ask for any certain answer to many of these tradeoff questions.

Other observations on what you've said:

- If you don't have a large dataset of posts, and well-labeled 'ground truth' for sentiment, your results may not be good. All these techniques benefit from larger training sets.
- Sentiment analysis is often approached as a classification problem (assigning texts to bins of 'positive' or 'negative' sentiment, operhaps of multiple intensities) or a regression problem (assigning texts a value on numerical scale). There are many more-simple ways to create features for such processes that do *not* involve word2vec vectors – a somewhat more-advanced technique, which adds complexity. (In particular, word-vectors only give you features for individual words, not texts of many words, unless you add some other choices/steps.) If new to the sentiment-analysis domain, I would recommend *against* starting with word-vector features. Only consider adding them later, after you've achieved some initial baseline results without their extra complexity/choices. At that point, you'll also be able to tell if they're helping or not.